# how to filter array in jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to filter jquery array like sql server "Like % %"

```
var array=[
{"job_category":"hello sir","job_location":"hello dear"},
{"job_category":"dear kumar ","job_location":"sir"},
{"job_category":"testts ssss ss","job_location":"hello test"}
```

]

```
var keyword="hello"
```

how to find keyword 'hello' in this array

Comment: This is not an array

Comment: Also, it is invalid syntax, you might want to do `var array = [...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
var arrays=[
    {"job_category":"hello sir","job_location":"hello dear"},
    {"job_category":"dear kumar ","job_location":"sir"},
    {"job_category":"testts ssss ss","job_location":"hello test"}
];

var keyword="hello";
  var search = new RegExp(keywods, "gi");
    var newarrays= $.grep(arrays, function (item) {
        return (item.job_category.match(search) || item.job_location.match(search))
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant to use an array, you could use [array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var array=[
    {"job_category":"hello sir","job_location":"hello dear"},
    {"job_category":"dear kumar ","job_location":"sir"},
    {"job_category":"testts ssss ss","job_location":"hello test"}
];

var keyword="hello";

var filteredArray = array.filter(function(item) { 
    return item.job_category.indexOf(keyword) != -1 || 
        item.job_location.indexOf(keyword) != -1;
});
```